# Is my data a good fit for a logistic or other binomial regression?

Tags: regression, logistic

I am trying to fit my data for a logistic regression for a decision to be made **YES** or **NO** or even **1** or **0**. I was wondering if my data is a good fit for this type of regression or should I use another tool. So far by trying the R regression tool I find the propabilites for all test data to be always YES. I might be doing something wrong. 
My question is: Is my data OK?

The code that I use with R is:

```
    #Data
    SRAB= read.csv2("T1.csv", header=T, sep=";")
    #Testfile
    TF= read.csv2("ttf.csv", header=T, sep=";")

    sapply(SRAB,function(x) sum(is.na(x)))

    model =glm(Y~X1+X2, data=SRAB, family=binomial)
    summary(model)
    glm.probs = predict (model, newdata=TF, type ="response")

    #create a table to check the probs
    predictions =rep("NO", 70)
    predictions [glm.probs >.5]="YES"
    predictions[1:70]
    table(predictions[1:70],Y[1:70])
```

[image: Data for logistic regression]

Below is the output with X1 as a factor:

```
   Call:
  glm(formula = Y ~ X1, family = binomial, data = SRAB)

  Deviance Residuals: 
 Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
 -1.97277  -0.00005   0.00005   0.00005   1.79412  
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Coefficients:    
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)    8.044e-01  2.918e-01   2.757  0.00584 **
X10.001     -2.137e+01  1.773e+04  -0.001  0.99904   
X10.002      1.119e-01  8.861e-01   0.126  0.89949   
X10.003     -1.903e+00  8.671e-01  -2.195  0.02818 * 
X10.004     -6.220e-01  6.722e-01  -0.925  0.35473   
X10.005     -1.092e+00  8.176e-01  -1.336  0.18165   
X10.006     -1.112e-01  7.649e-01  -0.145  0.88439   


omited..........................
......................................

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 1714.50  on 1360  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  473.08  on  365  degrees of freedom
AIC: 2465.1

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 19
```

and below is the output with X1 as a numeric:

```
   > summary(model)

 Call:
  glm(formula = Y ~ X1, family = binomial, data = SRAB)

  Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
  -1.5923  -1.4870   0.8932   0.8967   0.8967  

  Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
  (Intercept) 0.7034728  0.0640458  10.984   <2e-16 ***
  X1        0.0001905  0.0002014   0.946    0.344    
  ---
  Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

  (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 1575.2  on 1246  degrees of freedom
  Residual deviance: 1574.1  on 1245  degrees of freedom
    (114 observations deleted due to missingness)
  AIC: 1578.1

  Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
```

A slightly different data show better results using X3 which is X3=X1/1000

```
          Call:
          glm(formula = Y ~ X3, family = binomial, data = train)

   Deviance Residuals: 
Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
   -1.5932  -1.4685   0.9074   0.9119   0.9120  

   Coefficients:
         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
   (Intercept) 0.6623080  0.0750333   8.827   <2e-16 ***
   RABF        0.0002256  0.0002577   0.875    0.381    
   ---
   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

   (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

       Null deviance: 1165.4  on 913  degrees of freedom
   Residual deviance: 1164.6  on 912  degrees of freedom
     (86 observations deleted due to missingness)
   AIC: 1168.6

   Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

   > 
   > glm.probs = predict (model, newdata=test, type ="response")
   > 
   > predictions =rep("NO", 70)
   > 
   > predictions [glm.probs >.5]="YES"
   > predictions[1:70]
    [1] "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"               "YES"
   [13] "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"
   [25] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"
   [37] "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"
   [49] "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "NO"  "YES" "YES" "YES"
   [61] "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES" "YES"
   > table(predictions[1:70],Y[1:70])

         NO YES
     NO   3   2
     YES 20  45
   > FT[1:70]
    [1] NO  NO  YES NO  YES YES NO  YES YES YES NO  YES NO  YES NO  YES NO                                        YES NO                      
   [20] YES YES YES YES NO  YES NO  NO  YES NO  YES YES YES YES YES YES YES NO  YES
   [39] YES NO  YES YES YES NO  NO  NO  YES YES YES YES YES YES NO  YES YES YES NO 
   [58] YES YES YES YES YES YES YES YES NO  YES NO  YES NO 
   Levels: NO YES
```

data is below:
[image: Data with better results]

Comment: What's your model summary? Did you check your deviance?

Comment: Scaling a predictor should just change the model coefficient for it, and not affecting the overall fit of the model.

Comment: Your X1 variable seems to be a factor with about 1000 different levels. Is that what you intended?

Comment: I ve noticed that but even I converted to a number the situation is same. I ll post the summary for that one as well.

Comment: Your model hardly has any predictive power so it is predicting the same value for all cases. The model is correct and the predictions are correct.

Comment: There is slightly better results using different - modified in Excel - data from the same pool.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, your predictor doesn't give much predictive power to the binary outcomes. You can see that by noting your odds ratio (`exp(0.0002256)`) is about 1. That means, your predictor is independent (or very close) to the binary outcome. You may want to run chi-square independence to confirm.

This is bad news, because that's your only predictor. R is correct to tell you your model is statistically no different to a model with just the intercept. Therefore, your model predictions are all one, because your model is really predicting with just the intercept constant.